# How to find the index of the column of the minimum nonzero element across rows in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have an `nxm Array{Int64,2}` in Julia. I would like to find for each row, the index of the column of the minimum element that is not zero. If the row is zero then return 0.

For example, for `n=10` and `m=2` and

```
julia> A
10×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  0
 1  1
 8  7
 0  0
 3  8
 0  0
 0  0
 2  4
 5  1
 6  0
```

I would like to return

```
julia> B
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 1
```

What I did is this:

```
B = zeros(Int64, n);
for i in 1:n
    B[i] = findmin(A[i, :])[2];
end
```

but this does not work when there is a zero in some row...

Comment: What should this function do if there are negative values in a row?

Comment: If there are some zeros and some negative values, it should return the index of the minimum nonzero element. If all are zeros, it should return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `mapslices` and specify your function that works for a single row.

First, set up a matrix:

```
julia> A = [2 1; 1 2; -1 -2; 0 0; 0 5; 10 0]
6×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  2   1
  1   2
 -1  -2
  0   0
  0   5
 10   0
```

Create a function that finds the index of the minimal non-zero elements per row:

```
function findmincol(row)
    # handle the special case when all elements are 0
    if all(row .== 0)
        return 0
    end

    # check the number of zero elements
    length_zero = sum(row .== 0)

    # find the min among non-zero elements
    filter!(x -> x != 0, row)

    return findmin(row)[2] + length_zero
end
```

Then you can use `mapslices` to map the the `findmincol` function to each row of `A`:

```
mapslices(findmincol, A, dims=2)
```

This gives you (what I think is) the correct solution:

```
6×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 2
 1
 2
 0
 2
 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Most functions (`sum, minimum, find, findmin`, etc) take a `dims` keyword argument to specify the axis along which to do said operation:

Ex

```
findmin(rand(3, 4), dims=1)
 ([0.15952 0.0289172 0.409214 0.195433], CartesianIndex{2}[CartesianIndex(3, 1) 
 CartesianIndex(2, 2) CartesianIndex(3, 3) CartesianIndex(3, 4)])
```

returns the actual minima and the locations, as [Cartesian Indices](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex), as two separate arrays

So:

```
v, i = findmin(randn(10, 2), dims=2)
i = map(t -> t[2], i)
i[v .== 0] .= 0
```

The Cartesian Index is a little weird, but apparently used frequently for multi-dimensional indexing